# Why is my switch statement to select tabs not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, switch-statement, case

I am trying to display multiple images.  On click, a different text should be displayed.

I tried doing this by showing the text associated with image 1 as default, give the other images/text a `display: none;` and change that when the user clicks on the image by using the `switch` statement.  However, I seem to be missing something.  What am I missing?

Relevant JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){  
$("#list1 > li").click(function(e){  
    switch(e.target.id){  
        case "case1":  
            //change status &amp;amp;amp; style menu  
            $("#nav1").addClass("active");  
            $("#nav2").removeClass("active");  
            $("#nav3").removeClass("active");  
            $("#nav4").removeClass("active");  
            //display selected division, hide others  
            $("div.test1").fadeIn();  
            $("div.test2").css("display", "none");  
            $("div.test3").css("display", "none");  
            $("div.test4").css("display", "none"); 
        break;  
        case "case2":  
            //change status &amp;amp;amp; style menu  
            $("#nav1").removeClass("active");  
            $("#nav2").addClass("active");  
            $("#nav3").removeClass("active"); 
            $("#nav4").removeClass("active");   
            //display selected division, hide others  
            $("div.test2").fadeIn();  
            $("div.test1").css("display", "none");  
            $("div.test3").css("display", "none"); 
            $("div.test4").css("display", "none"); 
        break;  
        case "case3":  
            //change status &amp;amp;amp; style menu  
            $("#nav1").removeClass("active");  
            $("#nav2").removeClass("active");  
            $("#nav3").addClass("active");  
            $("#nav4").removeClass("active");
            //display selected division, hide others  
            $("div.test3").fadeIn();  
            $("div.test1").css("display", "none");  
            $("div.test2").css("display", "none"); 
            $("div.test4").css("display", "none"); 
        break;  
        case "case4":  
            //change status &amp;amp;amp; style menu  
            $("#nav1").removeClass("active");  
            $("#nav2").removeClass("active");  
            $("#nav4").addClass("active");  
            $("#nav3").removeClass("active");
            //display selected division, hide others  
            $("div.test3").fadeIn();  
            $("div.test1").css("display", "none");  
            $("div.test2").css("display", "none");  
            $("div.test4").css("display", "none");
        break;  
    }  
    //alert(e.target.id);  
    return false;  
});  
    });
```

Relevant HTML:

```
        <div id="slider">
<ul id="list1">
    <li id="nav1" class="active"><a href="#"><img src="test-img.jpg" style="width:156px;height:156px;"></a></li>
    <li id="nav2"><a href="#"><img src="test-img.jpg" style="width:156px;height:156px;"></a></li>
    <li id="nav3"><a href="#"><img src="test-img.jpg" style="width:156px;height:156px;"></a></li>
    <li id="nav4"><a href="#"><img src="test-img.jpg" style="width:156px;height:156px;"></a></li>
</ul>

    <div class="test1">
    <h2>Test tab</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut </p>
        <p>labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut </p>
        <p>aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse </p>
        <p>cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in </p>
        <p>culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="test2">
    <h2>Test tab2</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut </p>
        <p>labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut </p>
        <p>aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse </p>
        <p>cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in </p>
        <p>culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="test3">
    <h2>Test tab3</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut </p>
        <p>labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut </p>
        <p>aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse </p>
        <p>cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in </p>
        <p>culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `id`s of `li`s as `nav1`, `nav2`, etc. In the switch case, you are using `case1`, `case2`, etc.

Change that and things should start working.

Having said that, your jQuery is horribly bloated. It's called *the write less, do more JS library* for a reason, you know. :-)

**Update**: (Been doing this since a while on this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/izesar/1/edit). I know @roxon has got the exact same answer a minute back, but I'll post it here to make sure the time spent isn't useless )

```
$("#list1 > li").click(function(){  
  var index = $(this).index();
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  $('.test').hide().eq(index).fadeIn();
  return false;
});
```

This will work, with a small change to the html structure. Instead of having div classes as `test1`, `test2`, etc just have all the `div`s with a common class `test`

Comment: thanks for that, i knew it had to be something so stupid. Ur actual solution was something that didn't cross my mind actually. So a Big Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ajuxuc/1/edit)*

This is all you need:

```
$('#list1 li').eq( 0 ).addClass('active');
$('.test:gt(0)').hide();

$('#list1 li').click(function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  var myIndex = $(this).index();
  
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
  $('.test').hide().eq( myIndex ).fadeTo( 400,1 );  
});
```

Having this HTML structure example:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul id="list1">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>    
        <li></li> <!-- if you click this one "myIndex" will be '2' -->
        <li></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="test"></div>   <!-- .eq(0) --> 
    <div class="test"></div>   <!-- .eq(1) -->
    <div class="test"></div>   <!-- this is $('.test').eq(myIndex) -->  
    <div class="test"></div>   <!-- .eq(3) -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! ofcourse this is way more convenient than the page of coding i came up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#list1 > li").click(function(e){  
switch(e.target.id){  
    case "nav1":  
        //change status &amp;amp;amp; style menu  
        $("#nav1").addClass("active");  
        $("#nav2").removeClass("active");  
        $("#nav3").removeClass("active");  
        $("#nav4").removeClass("active");  
        //display selected division, hide others  
        $("div.test1").fadeIn();  
        $("div.test2").css("display", "none");  
        $("div.test3").css("display", "none");  
        $("div.test4").css("display", "none"); 
    break;  
    case "nav2":  
        //change status &amp;amp;amp; style menu  
        $("#nav1").removeClass("active");  
        $("#nav2").addClass("active");  
        $("#nav3").removeClass("active"); 
        $("#nav4").removeClass("active");   
        //display selected division, hide others  
        $("div.test2").fadeIn();  
        $("div.test1").css("display", "none");  
        $("div.test3").css("display", "none"); 
        $("div.test4").css("display", "none"); 
    break;  
    case "nav3":  
        //change status &amp;amp;amp; style menu  
        $("#nav1").removeClass("active");  
        $("#nav2").removeClass("active");  
        $("#nav3").addClass("active");  
        $("#nav4").removeClass("active");
        //display selected division, hide others  
        $("div.test3").fadeIn();  
        $("div.test1").css("display", "none");  
        $("div.test2").css("display", "none"); 
        $("div.test4").css("display", "none"); 
    break;  
    case "nav4":  
        //change status &amp;amp;amp; style menu  
        $("#nav1").removeClass("active");  
        $("#nav2").removeClass("active");  
        $("#nav4").addClass("active");  
        $("#nav3").removeClass("active");
        //display selected division, hide others  
        $("div.test3").fadeIn();  
        $("div.test1").css("display", "none");  
        $("div.test2").css("display", "none");  
        $("div.test4").css("display", "none");
    break;  
}  
//alert(e.target.id);  
return false;  
});  
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly the way we should **never** suggest to write code.